# Flutter graphically show the user that the List has more items

Tags: listview, flutter, items

I have a list of widgets with different heights. So it could be that the last item in the list is placed at the bottom of the screen and the user thinks the list is finished and does not recognize that he could scroll down.

Is there a way to graphically show that the user could scroll the list down?

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a multitude of sources, the easiest way will be to show a scrollbar for a few seconds after the page has been loaded.

Feel free to [check](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/24474) this post to find the best solution.